# Extracting a string from JNI GetByteArrayElements call

Tags: java, java-native-interface

To avoid the overhead of converting a byte[] to String, I am passing in the byte[] from Java to a native call. I use GetByteArrayElements to get access to the jbyte pointer and cast it to a (char *). At times, I see some non-ASCII characters printed using this approach.

After researching this, I understand this could happen if the java byte[] is not null terminated.

Question -

1. What is the best way to extract the characters from JNI when dealing
   with a byte[]?
2. On the java side, if I convert byte[] -> String -> byte[], will that add a null character at the end?

Comment: strlcpy might be suitable, no? (Your question assumes that the text from your external data source uses the same encoding that your native code needs.)

Comment: Yes, same encoding is used.

Comment: Any chance you have an example of how this would work with strlcpy?

Answer (score 1):

While you create byte array from string you hold some memory. You can pass **String** directly and save memory.

[Proper way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) of converting String (jstring in C++) to char* is:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_your_package_structure_className_myMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject jobj, jstring str) {

    char* native_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, JNI_FALSE);

    const char* hello = "hello ";
    char* hello_prefix = new char[6 + strlen(native_string)];
    strcpy(hello_prefix, hello);
    strcat(hello_prefix, native_string);
    /*
    call
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, str, native_string);
    if env->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, JNI_TRUE) was executed
    */

    jstring result = env->NewStringUTF(env, hello_prefix);
    delete[] hello_prefix;

    return result;
}
```

> const char* GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string,
>   jboolean *isCopy);
>
> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding. This array is valid until it is released by ReleaseStringUTFChars().
>   If isCopy is not NULL, then *isCopy is set to JNI_TRUE if a copy is made; or it is set to JNI_FALSE if no copy is made.

### Critical natives

While you works with primitive types, you can use fast critical natives functions to reduce overhead of java conversions. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309652/3926506) for details.

Comment: I am familiar with dealing with java strings and jstrings. I have a byte[] from some external datasource, hence I want to avoid the overhead to convert to java String

Comment: Look at [critical natives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36309652/3926506). You can reduce maximum overhead if your method can be converted to critical natives function