# JVM uses Java_xx method instead of JavaCritical_xx

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface

I have the following JNI code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_Test_callCritical
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass jobj_clazz)
{
  printf("I'm not critical\n");
  return 1;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JavaCritical_demo_Test_callCritical ()
{
  printf ("I'm critical\n");
  return 1;
}
```

And Kotlin code:

```
package demo

class Test {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        external fun callCritical(): Int
    }
}
```

If I run the program, it processes the Java method, not JavaCritical. I met all the conditions for running JavaCritical.

There is a similar question: [How to get JavaCritical to really work on JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730135/how-to-get-javacritical-to-really-work-on-jni) , but I build the native part and run it on MacOS.

UPD: I built under jvmTarget 1.8, the version of kotlin 1.3.61, and ran on jvm 1.8.0_222 and 11.0.2

Comment: Please edit your question to make an [mcve]. How are you compiling and testing this?

Comment: Your Kotlin code has `testCritical` while your JNI code has `callCritical` and expects a `demo` package. And we're still missing the code that _calls_ `callCritical`. Please take the effort to show us an actual [mcve].

Comment: @Botje Sorry, fixes added. But I can’t understand what kind of example is needed to call a function. The usual function call in main, but I think that you do not need to add this.

Comment: Please show the output of `nm libXXX.dylib | grep callCritical`. Before we go deeper I want to make sure the symbol is correctly defined.

Comment: I got the following: 
`0000000000000f50 T _JavaCritical_demo_Test_callCritical 0000000000000f20 T _Java_demo_Test_callCritical`

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298111/is-it-possible-to-use-sun-misc-unsafe-to-call-c-functions-without-jni/36309652#comment74659982_36309652) by @apangin is crucial:

> Only JIT compiled methods call Critical Natives. While a method is interpreted, it will call standard implementation.

I arrived at much the same conclusion by reading the JVM code, but it was good to see that confirmed.

I was able to force the `JavaCritical` function to fire by passing `-Xcomp` to my `java` invocation, which forces JIT compilation on the first call to a method. This is a [ridiculously terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021568/1548468), so I hope your general use case involves a hot loop around your JavaCritical function.

Finally, there may not be much point to all this. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/issues/86) measured JavaCritical JNI invocations and found them to be only marginally faster.

tl;dr: Unless this is for research purposes, you are better off abandoning the search for JavaCritical and using "plain" JNI (which ought to be fast enough already).

Comment: Thanks.
My function is called in an iterator, so this behavior suits me.