# Internally called JVM functions upon JNI

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

When a method defined in C is called from Java (using JNI), what are the methods that are invoked inside the JVM? What does the execution flow look like?

1. i.e. consider a method `public native void display()`. When this method is called from the java code as `object.display()`, what are the internal JVM methods that are called as execution proceeds towards the native code?
2. Where can I find more documentation about this? Alternatively, which JVM function in the source can I look at and trace?

Comment: To call a native method, HotSpot JVM enters a runtime stub (the fragment of machine code generated at VM startup). This runtime stub performs all the required JNI stuff - the procedure is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747484/3448419).

Comment: The sources for calling native methods from interpreter are in [`InterpreterGenerator::generate_native_entry`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/4d9931ebf861/src/cpu/x86/vm/templateInterpreter_x86_64.cpp#l960), or [`SharedRuntime::generate_native_wrapper`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/4d9931ebf861/src/cpu/x86/vm/sharedRuntime_x86_64.cpp#l1723) for calling native methods from JIT-compiled code.

Comment: The above is true for HotSpot JVM. Other JVMs may do this differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a look at exact chain of execution I suggest to connect to JVM using gdb (or CLion) and take a look at backtrace.

Take a look here to see how to do it:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2095

You can also take a look here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Cjeq4l5COU

Once you are attached to JVM, you can set breakpoint in your C code and check the backtrace from top to bottom.

Alternatively, you can create SIGSEGV and generate full backtrace of JVM (take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-015/)