# A list of Hotspot VM Operations with descriptions

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

Java Hotspot VM can do a number of different VM operations. When debugging safepoint times it's useful to know what was the purpose of the safepoint. Some of them are obvious: `G1IncCollectionPause` or `FindDeadlocks`, but some are not: `CGC_Operation`, `no vm operation`. There is VMOps.java, but it only lists possible values, not what they mean.

Currently, I need to know what `CGC_Operation` does in context of G1GC. I suspect that it is related to ConcurrentGCThread and Old gen collection, but I would like to confirm and also have some references to look for other operations.

Example:

```
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
...
128959.961: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2636 0 1 ] [ 0 0 0 15 52 ] 0
129986.695: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2637 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 12 51 ] 0
137019.250: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2636 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 13 50 ] 0
138693.219: CGC_Operation [ 2636 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 13 338 ] 0
138726.672: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2636 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 13 50 ] 0
138733.984: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2636 0 1 ] [ 0 0 0 13 50 ] 0
138738.750: G1IncCollectionPause [ 2636 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 13 62 ] 0
```

Comment: @Holger thanks, but this is a bit different thing. I need `operations`, not `options`.

Comment: When the documentation of the options, including the one which produces the output, doesn’t lead to a documentation of the output, I’m afraid, there is no documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (probably, the only) documentation is the source code. Fortunately, HotSpot JVM sources are very well commented.

See [src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/vm_operations_g1.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/ed8892ef0a8d/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/vm_operations_g1.hpp#l101):

```
// Concurrent GC stop-the-world operations such as remark and cleanup;
// consider sharing these with CMS's counterparts.
class VM_CGC_Operation: public VM_Operation {
```

`no vm operation` denotes the special type of periodic safepoint for various cleanup activities, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55405726/3448419)

Comment: Thanks, that'll probably do. I tried to web-search it, but it didn't work. Maybe after Skara it would be better.